# Swagger parameter error "is not exactly one from <#/definitions/parameter>"?

Tags: swagger

I'm trying to write a simple Swagger / Open API definition using the Swagger Editor.

```
swagger: "2.0"

info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: Test API
  description: Test API

schemes:
  - https
host: hipaa.ai
basePath: /v1

paths:
  /comments:
    post:
      summary: Your comments
      description: Comments
      parameters:
      - name: text
        in: body
        description: An array of text strings
        type: array
        minItems: 1
        maxItems: 1000
        items:
          type: text
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Schema error at paths./comments.post.parameters[0]
is not exactly one from <#/definitions/parameter>,<#/definitions/jsonReference>
```

I've checked the Swagger schema reference, and the petstore example, but I'm not sure why I'm getting this.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Body parameters use the `schema` keyword to specify the type, so you need to move `type`, `items`, `minItems` and `maxItems` under `schema`.

Also, `type: text` is not a [valid type](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#data-types). Use `type: string` instead.

```
      parameters:
      - name: text
        in: body
        description: An array of text strings
        schema:
          type: array
          minItems: 1
          maxItems: 1000
          items:
            type: string
```