# Swagger error with parameters in a multipart POST request

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

I'm using Swagger Editor to document an existing API, built in Node, but it keeps giving me the following error:

> Schema error at paths./upload/Rate.post.parameters[0]
>       is not exactly one from <#/definitions/parameter>,<#/definitions/jsonReference>

This error appears in 3 places of my code:

- paths./upload/Rate.post.parameters[0]
- paths./upload/Rate.post.parameters[1]
- paths./users/register.post.parameters[0]

I've searched quite a bit, but, for example, this link did not solved my problem although it's the same error:

[Swagger parameter error "is not exactly one from <#/definitions/parameter>"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43592634/swagger-parameter-error-is-not-exactly-one-from-definitions-parameter)

Here is my Swagger definition:

```
  /users/register:
    post:
      tags:
      - "users"
      description: Allows an user to register at the Server
      produces:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - name: body
          in: body
          description: JSON Object with information for a Register request from an User
          schema: 
            type: object
            required:
              - username
              - password
              - weight
              - height
              - gender
              - restRate
              - age
            properties:
              username:
                type: string
              password:
                type:
                format: password
              weight:
                type: integer
              height:
                type: integer
              gender:
                type: string
              restRate:
                type: integer
              age: 
                type: integer
      # Expected responses for this operation:
      responses:
        # Response code
        200:
          description: Register successful
          schema:
            type: string

  /upload/Rate:
    post:
      tags:
      - "upload"
      description: Allows an user to upload a file into the server
      produces:
        - application/json
      consumes: 
        - multipart/form-data
      parameters:
        - name: body
          in: formData
          description: JSON Object with information for an upload request from an User
          required: false
          schema:
            type: object
            required:   
              - user
              - overlap
              - window 
              - latitude
              - longitude
              - time
              - date
            properties:
              user:
                type: string
              overlap:
                type: string
              window:
                type: string
              latitude:
                type: string
              longitude:
                type: string
              time:
                type: string
              date:
                type: string
        - name: files 
          in: formData
          description: File with the corresponding Rate
          required: false
          schema:
            type: object
            required:
              - rate
            properties:
              rate:
                type: file
      # Expected responses for this operation:
      responses:
        # Response code
        200:
          description: Login successful
          schema:
            type: string
```

Maybe this will help, but the post route (upload/Rate) should receive a request that will be something like this, once I've parsed its parameters:

```
user = req.body.user;
rr = req.files.rate;
overlap = req.body.overlap;
windowT = req.body.window;
latitude = req.body.latitude;
longitude = req.body.longitude;
time = req.body.time;
date = req.body.date;
```

Thank you for your help and time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues.

`/upload/register`:

- Schema property `password` is missing the value for `type`.
- Property name mismatch - `restHR` (under `properties`) vs `restRate` (in the `required` list).

`upload/Rate`:

- The problem here is caused by object parameters in a `multipart/form-data` request. In OpenAPI (fka Swagger) 2.0, form parameters can be primitive values and arrays, but not objects. So your example cannot be described using OpenAPI 2.0.

  If you were designing a new API (or if you could and were willing to change the API implementation to be compatible with OpenAPI 2.0), possible solutions would be:

  - Change the operation to consume `application/json` and combine all input parameters into a single JSON object. The file parameter would need to be implemented as a base64 string - `type: string` with `format: byte`.
  - Use `multipart/form-data` but split object parameters into individual form parameters.

  The upcoming OpenAPI 3.0 will support object parameters in form data:
  https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/OpenAPI.next/versions/3.0.md#special-considerations-for-multipart-content